# OneLogin not passing RelayState query parameter back to SP (embedded in my application)

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I used OneLogin's java integration toolkit, I'm able to log into default home page of my application using SAML SSO. But, I need the url that user requested initially to redirect. Unfortunately, OneLogin is not returning RelayState param during SAML assertion to my application. Or should I be passing it as different query param ?

Note: This is SP initiated SSO.

Answer (score 0):

We will be updating the Java toolkit soon to modernize it and bring a whole bunch of SAML features.

Comment: Is there a workaround to preserve target resource URL during a SP initiated SSO using OneLogin ?

Answer (score 0):

RelayState is an opaque token that references the original URL that the user was trying to access (or resource within the app). The OneLogin Java SAML SDK will send an AuthRequest to the IdP but does not automatically parse the URL and send a token to the IdP.

A simple extension to your use of the toolkit would be the following:

1.) When a user accesses a protected page, check for session.
2.) If no active sesssion (ie. no cookie etc) then determine if the user is part of an org where SAML based SSO is enabled (either through a URL subdomain or request the user's email address.. etc)
3.) Your app, after determining the user is not logged in and should be auth'd against an IdP, can then utilize the out of the box code in OneLogin's SAML Toolkit to send the SAMLRequest to the stored HTTP Endpoint in the Settings.java file.
4.) Create an additional function in the authrequest.java file to create the RelayState token, this could be as simple as parsing the URL and then URL Encoding it.
5.) Call that function in the java-saml / sample / src / main / webapp / index.jsp logic of your app, and use it to add the variable ?RelayState={yourtoken} to the auth request. This will be preserved through the entire workflow, at the end just parse it back out and use it for a simple redirect.

Very best!